# Microsoft Graph API SDK for SharePoint to query a file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to use Graph API SDK to query a file in a SharePoint site

```
        var site = await graphClient.Sites["myDomain"]
            .SiteWithPath("relativePath").Request()
            .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var drive = await graphClient.Sites["myDomain]
            .SiteWithPath("relativePath").Lists["mylib"].Drive
            .Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var file = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id]
            .Drives[drive.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("/folder1").Children["myfile.txt"]
            .Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is working and I get the file.

I try to combine the three steps into one,

```
        var file = await graphClient.Sites["myDomain"]
            .SiteWithPath("relativePath").Lists["mylib"].Drive
            .Root.ItemWithPath("/folder1").Children["myfile.txt"]
            .Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But it gives Bad Request error. What's wrong? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What error message do you get? I imagine `Url specified is invalid` because Graph does not understand any path beyond `/sites/your-domain:/sites/site-name:/lists/your-lib/drive`

Answer (score 0):

The navigation you are using is not accepted by Graph.
As per the [get files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) docs, you need the site-id.

```
# Valid
GET /sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/relativePath/lists/mylib/drive

# Invalid addition to above url
GET /sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/relativePath/lists/mylib/drive/root:/myfile.txt:
```

If you don't have the site id, you can expand the list relationship in the get list drive call and use the site-id to request for the file. This will be two requests instead.

```
var drive = await graphServiceClient
    .Sites["mydomain.sharepoint.com"]
    .SiteWithPath(relativePath)
    .Lists["mylib"]
    .Drive
    .Request()
    .Expand("list")
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var file = await graphServiceClient
    .Sites[drive.List.ParentReference.SiteId]
    .Drives[drive.Id]
    .Root.ItemWithPath("/Folder 1")
    .Children["myfile.txt"]
    .Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```